# Library to Help Loop with Generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I found I need to loop through a list to create a brute force algorithm. Therefore, I decided to make a library, but to generalize the result by using a generator. There are three cases which is every single element, every pair of elements, and every triple of elements. The cases store a variable which contains the generator function. Currently, the generator is required to be nested with no parameters inside a function which takes the data structure as a parameter. Therefore, the average space complexity is O(1) in the three cases. The code is below.

```
def test_generator():
    yield "a"
    yield "b" 
    
def singles(generator):
    """
    average time: O(n) where n is the number of yields from generator 
    average space: O(1) 
    """
    for at in generator():
        yield at 

def test_singles():
    assert list(singles(test_generator)) == ["a", "b"]
    
def pairs(generator):
    """
    average time: O(n * n) where n is the number of yields from generator 
    average space: O(1) 
    """
    first_generator = generator 
    second_generator = generator 
    for first in first_generator():
        second_generator = generator 
        for second in second_generator():
            yield first, second 

def test_pairs():
    assert list(pairs(test_generator)) == [("a", "a"), ("a", "b"), ("b", "a"), ("b", "b")]
    
def triples(generator):
    """
    average time: O(n * n * n) where n is the number of yields 
    average sapce: O(1) 
    """
    first_generator = generator 
    second_generator = generator 
    third_generator = generator 
    for first in first_generator():
        second_generator = generator 
        for second in second_generator():
            third = third_generator 
            for third in third_generator():
                yield first, second, third 
    
def test_triples():
    assert list(triples(test_generator)) == [("a", "a", "a"), ("a", "a", "b"), ("a", "b", "a"),
    ("a", "b", "b"), ("b", "a", "a"), ("b", "a", "b"), ("b", "b", "a"), ("b", "b", "b")]

    
def tests():
    test_singles() 
    test_pairs()
    test_triples() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Unnecessary variables

```py
def pairs(generator):
    """
    average time: O(n * n) where n is the number of yields from generator 
    average space: O(1) 
    """
    first_generator = generator 
    second_generator = generator 
    for first in first_generator():
        second_generator = generator 
        for second in second_generator():
            yield first, second
```

The value of `second_generator` does not change in the loop.  Therefore, the assignment to `second_generator` in the loop may be omitted.

```py
def pairs(generator):
    """
    average time: O(n * n) where n is the number of yields from generator 
    average space: O(1) 
    """
    first_generator = generator 
    second_generator = generator 
    for first in first_generator():
        for second in second_generator():
            yield first, second
```

In fact, the value of `generator` never changes, so `first_generator` and `second_generator` always equal `generator`.  Thus `first_generator` and `second_generator` are redundant variables and may be omitted entirely.

```py
def pairs(generator):
    """
    average time: O(n * n) where n is the number of yields from generator 
    average space: O(1) 
    """
    for first in generator():
        for second in generator():
            yield first, second
```

Identical improvements may be applied to the `triples` function.

## Useless assignment

```py
            third = third_generator 
            for third in third_generator():
                yield first, second, third
```

The assignment to `third` before the loop is immediately overwritten by the `for ... in ...` loop statement, which also assigns values to `third`.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is basically equivalent to [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), you should check it out.

Comment: From the documentation, "_Before product() runs, it completely consumes the input iterables, keeping pools of values in memory to generate the products. Accordingly, it is only useful with finite inputs._"  This means the average space would not remain \$O(1)\$.